# Managing session in PHP AWS

Tags: php, mysql, session, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a website which is hosted on AWS, I cant trust this session array `$_SESSION[]` as sometime `select * from table_name where id=$_SESSION[id]` doesn't work as expected.
I am looking for some session management trick, is it ok If I use Database or Dyanmo DB.
If there is a scalable application which has lot of user on it.what would be the prefered way for doing it?

Comment: If you're only hosting on a single box, then there should be no problem with sessions (unless there is a problem with your code) and switching to a database would make no difference then; if you're distributing load across multiple webheads, then you either need sticky sessions (so all activity from the same user/session is directed to the same webhead), or a session that's accessible from all webheads - elasticache is one obvious example of such a distributed session handling option

Comment: Do you do any [SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/) whatsoever on that value?

Comment: @MarkBaker yes there are many webheads (instances)

Comment: @tadman I will surely

Comment: Are you currently storing sessions outside of the web front end instances or are you still using files?

Comment: @datasage I am using on the same web front

Comment: @user1765876 If an instance fails, the user will loose their session and will need to start over with a new session on a different web front. It will be much better to store sessions in memcached. You can do this very easy using the php-memcache extension and with an elastic cache instance (or two).

Comment: @datasage php memcache will be on elastic cache?

Comment: @user1765876 ElasticCache is memcached. Just has some extra management tools on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 basic options for storing sessions in php: file based, memcached, and database backed.

If you use file based session, then you need to use sticky sessions, so subsequent requests from the same user get routed back to the same instance.  This may not work if you are using autoscaling - if an instance is stopped, then that user will lose his session.

You can use memcached, where there is a single memcached instance that stores session.  This is probably the easiest option.  No state is saved on the instances, and you do not need to use sticky session. As long as you don't exceed the available memory for memcached, you should be OK.

The third option is to use a database backed session.  This should have the same effect as using memcached sessions, but does allow more complex behavior - for instance, you can replicate your databases across datacenters and theoretically that allows you to have an application that scales across multiple regions.

Comment: is there any tutorial for option 2 and option 3?